# How to make Graphic to make Chart and Material Design

Tags: java, android, charts

I am developing application with a lot of charts  but sadly, too much dependency which I can't customizing by my self. I want to work with a very basic graphic, so I can create my own chart, my own NumberProgress bar, and everything about graphic. What should I do to make my own chart and where to get started to make my own chart without dependency of two chart libraries below? my problem is i don't know anything about graphic.

You know free [MPAndroid Chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) or [Hello Chart](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android), I am asking how the man building the chart system, like Graphic pixel, colors and zoom? But the chart that he make too simple, that is the reason and my goal is to make system chart like pic below, what should i do?

[image]

[link for the image](https://id.pinterest.com/pin/567523990525675550/)

Comment: The question is very unclear? Are you asking how to get started creating your own charting library? Or do you want to implement one?

Comment: @DTul thanks man, just fix it

Comment: And what is the problem you are having?

Comment: Then i'd suggest looking at [Images and Graphics](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics) and [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) as charts and graphs are basically formatted images

Comment: Are you sure you have the permission to copy and reproduce this image here?

Comment: @DTul i think like that it what i am looking for do you want put as the answer?

Comment: @LutzHorn i just put the link,

Comment: thanks man, just edit@jbx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by looking at [Images](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics) and Graphics and [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas) as charts and graphs are basically formatted images.